A bird in a container
Suppose there is a bird in a sealed container, and the container is on a scale that measures its weight. The bird is flapping its wings to hover in the middle of the container. If the bird flaps its wings faster to accelerate upwards, what will happen to the scale reading? Will it increase, decrease, or remain unchanged?

Sounds like an experiment you could do at home if you substitute a remote controlled quad copter for the bird.

@SolomonSlow thanks for the suggestion. I do not have resources to perform the experiment. What would be your guess?

This question is similar to: Bird flying in an open or a closed cage. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Friendly reminder that answers to questions should be posted as answers, not as comments.
